# Hiding Custom List types on the Quick Launch programmatically

Tags: 2010, quick-launch

I would like to mimic the functionality of "List Settings > General Settings > Display this list on the Quick Launch" at deploy time. 
I.E. I want to hide custom list types from being displayed on the Quick Launch menu. What's the best way of doing it?
Also, would it be possible to display them on custom pages using a custom master page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the list's OnQuickLaunch property to False.